# Could you tell us please when the data on the map will be updated?

Tags: service, new-operator, renewal, point-of-interest

We are adding POI on the map in the the Troitsky and Novomoskovsky administrative districts from 27th May. Could you tell us please when the data will be updated? We are launching a new service in this area and this data is required

Comment: POI here means Point of Interest, right? I don't understand why you ask general developers for updates on a map provider service (google / here maps / ...) - it is definitely not a Apache POI related questions and most probably the wrong forum to ask for ...

Comment: See my comment to the OP - there is probably not a stackexchange forum for this question